# Vector Line Equation

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Consider the lines $l_{1}$ and $l_{2}$ defined by equation $ax+\left ( a-1 \right )y = 0$ and $bx+by=1$, respectively where $b\neq 0$.

Find the coordinate of the intersection point of the lines $l_{1}$ and $l_{2}$ in terms of $a$ and $b$

I confused with the equation and how to change that equation to vector equation form.

Comment: Actually need the vector form? $(-b,a)$ is the directing vector of a line $ax+by+c=0$ on the $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane, since $(a,b)$ is the normal one.

Comment: I can solve it by using substitution-elimination and get the coordinate is : ($\frac{a}{b}$,$\frac{1-a}{b}$). But how to solve it using vector way...?

Comment: I'd consider a line equation in vector form and another in normal (scalar, general) form, then substitute, like for a line-vs-plane intersection in 3d. $ax+(a-1)y=0$ is more simple to translate to the vector form, as the point $(0,0)$ lays on it (by inspection). So the vector form is $\frac{x}{1-a}=\frac{y}{a}=t$ or $\mathbf{r}=(x,y)=t(1-a,a)$.

Comment: Yes! It's my problem here... I still not understand about changing cartesian form to vector form.... How you did that?

Comment: After watching some tutorials from youtube, i can change the $l_{1}$ equation to vector become like this : $\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}+\lambda \begin{pmatrix}
\left ( \frac{1}{a}-1 \right )\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}$. And $l_{2}$ become : $\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{b}\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}+\lambda \begin{pmatrix}
-1\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}$. Are they true? If false, please tell me where is the trouble come from...

Comment: It's correct, in my view.

Comment: For finding the intersection coordinate, what vector must I add into cross product? before plus sign or after plus sign (with lambda)?